# Simple bash script failing when installed on Crontab

Tags: ubuntu, bash, cron

EDIT:My script is located at $HOME folder.This is the reason of the issue.More details by the end of the question.In any case,this is not a duplicate question!

I have a quite trivial script deleting some log files.Running perfectly from command line.
However,If I install it on crontab,sporadically I get

> /bin/sh: 1: $MyScript.sh: not found

I thought that might be related with crontab config so I have installed it into crontab specifically for my user via

```
sudo vi /etc/crontab
```

Unfortunately I still keep getting the same error intemittently.
Below is my script.

```
#!/bin/sh
NOW=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y-%T")
echo "$NOW Starting deleting of  log files"
find /$PATH_TO_DIR/logs/* -mtime +30 -type f -delete

if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
 echo "$NOW Successfully deleted files"
else
 echo "$NOW Could not delete files"
fi
```

Any help appreciated.

EDIT:
Issue was my home folder being encrypted.That is why it was intemittently working,only when I was logged in to terminal.(Then home folder is decrypted and my schript is found). So I moved my script to somewhere else and it started working.

Comment: "specifically for my user via" That's not how you edit the per-user crontab.

Comment: I have added the line below using "sudo vi /etc/crontab" `0 6    * * *   myuser  path_to_my_script.sh >> /tmp/deleteOldLogoutput.txt 2>&1` What is wrong with this set up?

Answer (score 0):

There are several issues:

crontabs (whether `crontab -e` or files in `/etc/cron.d` are specified as follows:

```
17 *    * * *   root    /usr/local/bin/script.sh
```

This example runs on th 17th minute of every hour, as root.

You can, however, put normal scripts in `/etc/cron.daily/` (or weekly, monthly, hourly). Note: don't put a `.` in the filename then, it will be skipped.

Your script also references undefined variables. This will result in the path `/logs/*` being used, because `$PATH_TO_DIR` evaluates to empty. You could fix that by running `set -u` somewhere at the start of your script (disclaimer: I don't know how non-bash shells deal with that).

I also think we're missing information, because I don't see any reference to `$MyScript`

Comment: $PATH_TO_DIR and $MyScript are placeholders for folder and scriptname,which I don't want to disclose since they include company/product name. So they are all fine. As to the crontab,I have added the line below using "sudo vi /etc/crontab"  `0 6    * * *   myuser  path_to_my_script.sh >> /tmp/deleteOldLogoutput.txt 2>&1`   What is wrong with this set up?

Comment: If you have clarifying comments, edit your original question. The comment box is made layoutless on purpose.

Comment: No need for clarification for this regard. I have edited the question with the solution.